# How I get Active Directory User Properties with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement Namespace?

Tags: c#, properties, active-directory, principal, userprincipal

I want do get Active Directory Properties from a user and I want to use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

my code:

```
public static void GetUserProperties(string dc,string user) 
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc);
            UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

            string firstname = u.GivenName;
            string lastname = u.Surname;
            string email = u.EmailAddress;
            string telephone = u.VoiceTelephoneNumber;

            ...//how I can get company and other properties?
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean company?

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785751/how-to-get-company-and-department-from-active-directory-given-a-userprincipa

Comment: i would also need the same without using extension methods for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 22):

You can transition into the DirectoryServices namespace to get any property you need.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, dc);
UserPrincipal u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

string firstname = u.GivenName;
string lastname = u.Surname;
string email = u.EmailAddress;
string telephone = u.VoiceTelephoneNumber;
string company = String.Empty;

...//how I can get company and other properties?
if (userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObjectType() == typeof(DirectoryEntry))
{
    // Transition to directory entry to get other properties
    using (var entry = (DirectoryEntry)userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject())
    {
        if (entry.Properties["company"] != null)
            company = entry.Properties["company"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the proppertie dont forget to call userPrincipal.save() after you changed the value.

```
entry.Properties["company"].value = company;
userPrincipal.save();
```