# Getting Current Logon Username from LDAP in asp web app

Tags: asp.net, ldap

Trying to get the current logon username on client side in asp web app.

I am able to get the username like this

```
<domain_name>/<user>
CCI\Waqar
```

But I want to extract the client name in this format

```
Waqar.Ahmed/Technology/Lahore
```

I can get it while running on Localhost. But when I deploy the package on web server it gives me exception.

Following is the code by which i am able to get on Localhost.

```
try
         {
             UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
             sUser = userPrincipal.DisplayName;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return ex.Message.ToString();
         }
```

tried googling a lot but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things

- a typical username with domain authentication is `domain\login` and cannot be xxx/xxx/xxx as per your example. Most likely you refer to a *display name*, and/or department/location or other attributes of the user. See [How to get "Company" and "Department" from Active Directory given a UserPrincipal object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785751/how-to-get-company-and-department-from-active-directory-given-a-userprincipa) for more details.
- the difference between test and server environment is due to different accounts used on IIS (or different web.config). Check IIS settings and also try to use the domain context e.g.

  ```
  PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
  UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
  ```